# Why do I get a stack overflow error when running librtmp on esp32

Tags: c, esp32, rtmp, esp-idf, rtmpdump

I'm currently using esp32 to stream audio, using librtmp, idf-v4.3 library. librtmp works fine when I use [espressif/arduino-esp32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) library, but get a lot of stack overflow errors when using [espressif/esp-idf](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf) , whether to put librtmp in Internal SRAM or External SRAM.

I found through debugging that the problem probably occurred in the socket send() function:

```
int RTMPSockBuf_Send(RTMPSockBuf *sb, const char *buf, int len)
{
    int rc;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    fwrite(buf, 1, len, netstackdump);
#endif

#if defined(CRYPTO) && !defined(NO_SSL)
    if (sb->sb_ssl)
    {
        rc = TLS_write(sb->sb_ssl, buf, len);
    }
    else
#endif
    {
        printf("socket send:%p len:%d heap:%d\n", buf, len, esp_get_free_internal_heap_size());
        rc = send(sb->sb_socket, buf, len, 0);
        printf("socket send return\n");
    }
    return rc;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
I (559) wifi:wifi driver task: 3ffc0744, prio:23, stack:6656, core=0
I (639) wifi_init: tcp mss: 1440
I (639) wifi_init: WiFi IRAM OP enabled
I (639) wifi_init: WiFi RX IRAM OP enabled
I (649) phy_init: phy_version 4670,719f9f6,Feb 18 2021,17:07:07
I (759) wifi:mode : sta (34:ab:95:77:59:e0)
I (759) wifi:enable tsf
I (759) wifi station: wifi_init_sta finished.
I (799) wifi:new:<6,1>, old:<1,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<6,1>, prof:1
I (799) wifi:state: init -> auth (b0)
I (809) wifi:state: auth -> assoc (0)
I (809) wifi:state: assoc -> run (10)
I (939) wifi:connected with TIMO_1, aid = 2, channel 6, 40U, bssid = 88:25:93:1a:41:64
I (939) wifi:security: WPA2-PSK, phy: bgn, rssi: -59
I (939) wifi:pm start, type: 1

W (949) wifi:<ba-add>idx:0 (ifx:0, 88:25:93:1a:41:64), tid:0, ssn:0, winSize:64
I (999) wifi:AP's beacon interval = 102400 us, DTIM period = 1
I (1549) esp_netif_handlers: sta ip: 192.168.0.102, mask: 255.255.255.0, gw: 192.168.0.1
I (1549) wifi station: got ip:192.168.0.102
I (1549) wifi station: connected to ap SSID:TIMO_1 password:********
into rtmp_connect
into RTMP_Connect0
into RTMP_Connect1
socket send:0x3ffb9e99 len:1537 heap:216508

***ERROR*** A stack overflow in task main has been detected.


Backtrace:0x400819e6:0x3ffb9b000x40088341:0x3ffb9b20 0x4008b802:0x3ffb9b40 0x40089fc6:0x3ffb9bc0 0x40088440:0x3ffb9be0 0x400883f2:0x0000000c  |<-CORRUPTED
0x400819e6: panic_abort at C:/Users/q1004/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/panic.c:402

0x40088341: esp_system_abort at C:/Users/q1004/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/esp_system.c:121

0x4008b802: vApplicationStackOverflowHook at C:/Users/q1004/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/port.c:394

0x40089fc6: vTaskSwitchContext at C:/Users/q1004/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:3505

0x40088440: _frxt_dispatch at C:/Users/q1004/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/portasm.S:436

0x400883f2: _frxt_int_exit at C:/Users/q1004/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/portasm.S:231
```

Has anyone had the same problem, I will put the whole project on [github](https://github.com/TimoQAQ/esp-rtmp-debug). help.

Comment: Hi liuyang, welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see more code. The code you provided doesn't tell us anything about the arguments to the function you provided, and they're probably where the issue arises. We ask that you provide a [minimal, reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code that demonstrates the problem. Basically chop out everything that's unnecessary, make sure it still compiles and still causes the problem, and share the entire thing in your question, not as a link. Otherwise we have to guess what's going on.

Comment: This is where we ask for a [mre].  Chances are slim that the `send()` call is the actual problem.  More likely than not, the issue revolves around the path by which execution actually reaches that call.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're getting a stack overflow in the main task.

Try increasing the main task stack size:

`make menuconfig` -> `Component Config` -> `ESP System settings` -> `Main task stack size`

The relevant `sdkconfig` setting is [`CONFIG_ESP_MAIN_TASK_STACK_SIZE`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/kconfig.html#config-esp-main-task-stack-size) (formerly `CONFIG_MAIN_TASK_STACK_SIZE`).

Also important to read: [Reducing Stack Sizes](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/performance/ram-usage.html#reducing-stack-sizes).